# Java Graph to PDF

Tags: java, pdf, graph

I have created my own structures for representing mathematical graphs in Java. Now i need a library that supports creating a PDF file with that graph. Does anyone know a Java library that supports creating PDF files with graphs. By graph i mean something like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Directed_acyclic_graph_3.svg/1280px-Directed_acyclic_graph_3.svg.png). I need a library that could emulate functions like LaTex `ncline` and `ncarc`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: consider Apache FOP: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/quickstartguide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest answer is to use LaTex `Tikz and PGF` and call the `pdflatex` command from inside the java code, then check if the PDF creation was successful. Keep in mind that the program will be dependent on `LaTex` being installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

* [GraphPanel](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel)

* [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/)

* [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/)

then, render to pdf using: [iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/)